# jQuery Droppable, get the element dropped

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

A small question hopefully with a simple answer, I am using jQuery draggable and droppable to place items into a dock. Using the below code for the drop.

```
$("#dock").droppable({
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                //Do something to the element dropped?!?
            }
        });
```

However I couldn't find a way to get what element was actually dropped, so I can do something do it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

From the [drop event documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#event-drop):

> This event is triggered when an
> accepted draggable is dropped 'over'
> (within the tolerance of) this
> droppable. In the callback, `$(this)`
> represents the droppable the draggable
> is dropped on. While `ui.draggable` represents
> the draggable.

So:

```
$("#dock").droppable({
     drop: function(event, ui) {
               // do something with the dock
               $(this).doSomething();

               // do something with the draggable item
               $(ui.draggable).doSomething();
           }
});
```

Comment: Do the active css classes need to be removed

Comment: For me, this leaves the element with drag state, position: relatative and left/right co-ordinates

Comment: How exactly do you select the draggable within the doSomething() function?

Comment: This code is working.
`$("#drag").draggable();
$("#drop").droppable({
 drop: function (event, ui) {
  $(this).css("background-color","red");
 }
});
$("#drop").droppable({
 out: function( event, ui ) {

 $(this).css("background-color","yellow");
 }
});`


why this code is not working?


`$("#drag").draggable();
$("#drop").droppable({
 drop: function (event, ui) {
  $(this).css("background-color","red");
 }
 out: function( event, ui ) {

 $(this).css("background-color","yellow");
 }
});`

[codepen](http://codepen.io/maxyspark/pen/WwOxgQ)

Comment: I had to use ui.draggable[0] . ui.draggable is an array.