# jquery draggable stop event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I have searched a lot of.But I can't find answer.Maybe dublicate.Here is a bit of my code:

```
$(".box").draggable({
        revert:"invalid",
        stop:function(ev,ui){
            //if(dropped) alert(ui.item.attr("id");
            //else alert("Not dropped");
        }
    });
$(".box").droppable({
        accept:function(drag){
            return $(drag).attr("data-id")===$(this).attr("data-id");
        },
        drop:function(ev,ui){

        }
    });
```

I have looked [droppable options](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-greedy) and [draggable options](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop).But it isn't helpfull.In other word how to access dropped element using draggable options,events and methods.
Also dublicate with [jQuery Droppable, get the element dropped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975091/jquery-droppable-get-the-element-dropped)

How to get the dropped element Id if it is dropped from Draggable stop function.

Comment: you haven't explained what your problem is and what you need to achieve

Comment: Actually his question is on stopping he want to display the element Id.

Comment: I want to get dropped element id with draggable stop event or inside stop event check dragged element drop any element

Comment: you cant make it from draggable, there is no event or anything named dropped in draggable and you cant use it in stop: function of draggable.

Answer (score 3):

It's easy to get one in `droppable`. But not with `draggable` there's hacky way to get id of dropped element on stop event in `draggable`...

I tried it in my previous projects, works like charm.

Try this :

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable(
      { handle: "p",
        stop: function(event, ui){
          console.log(event);
          console.log($(ui.helper[0]).children().attr('id'));
     }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rahulrulez/gg4z10v4/

Answer (score 1):

I use this and it works for me:

```
   $trash2.droppable({
        accept: "#gallery > li",
        activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            deleteImage(ui.draggable);
        }
    });
```