# How to track jQuery drag and drop feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I am using bootstrap with jQuery UI to create drag and drop feature for my lists.

My HTML is:

```
<ul class="draggablePanelList list-unstyled">
    <li class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">You can drag this panel.</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Content ...</div>
    </li>
    <li class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">You can drag this panel too.</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Content ...</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My script which makes the drag and drop feature work:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var panelList = $('.draggablePanelList');

    panelList.sortable({
        // Only make the .panel-heading child elements support dragging.
        // Omit this to make then entire <li>...</li> draggable.
        update: function() {
            $('.panel', panelList).each(function(index, elem) {
                 var $listItem = $(elem),
                     newIndex = $listItem.index();

                 // Persist the new indices.
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I want to add javascript which indicates which item was dragged and dropped and where it is now in the list (using a element attribute to track). How can I do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are draggable and resizable functions in the UI. I use the following to handle events once it's finished resizing:

```
.resizable('stop' : function(){ doSomething.call(this); }.bind(this))
```

You could include the same binding to your drag 'n drop UI function. You may have to add a listener to get the target of the list item.

Edit: Here's the [draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) function:

```
.draggable({ 'stack'       : '.classContainer', 
             'handle'      : '.classThatHandlesDrag', 
             'containment' : '#divThatLimitsTheDrag' })
```

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. Now is there a way to indicate which item was dragged and dropped and where it is now on the list.

Comment: you can handle UI events, as shown in the `.resizable` code I posted above, here's one for draggable: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25363015/1837472 Just use `function(event){` and you can use `$(this)` to see what triggered the drag.

Comment: okay thanks i will work on this and get back to see if can come up with the specific solution for the question

Comment: i was unable to use this to track the drag and drop feature